# Can snyk be configured to ignore all issues for a particular maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven, snyk

I would like to clarify some moments regarding snyk ignore.
Is it possible to configure **.snyk file** to ignore all kinds of issues for a particular maven dependency.
https://docs.snyk.io/snyk-cli/commands/ignore

```
ignore:
  '*':  //<ISSUE_ID> all issues
    - 'path to maven dependecny':    // <PATH_TO_RESOURCE>
      reason: <REASON>
      expires: <EXPIRY>
```

I suppose it will not work as here issues' ids  should be specified.
Anyway. I would be grateful for any piece of advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today the `.snyk` file can ignore:

- a file
- a folder
- a issue ID (vulnerability or license issue)

Today it doesn't allow to ignore a specific dependency. If you have an Enterprise plan you may ignore at scale the CVEs associated to this dependency in the **Policies** tab in the Group level today, it is not ideal but some kind of workaround.

You may also use the ignore button in the UI but it will be on a *per-project* *per-vuln* basis